# UISegmentedControll appearance no border sharp edges

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm therribly upset. I've spent lot of time and no suitable result.

I want to redesign (AS APPEARANCE) this

[image]

to this

[image]

Or in programmatic words... from this:

```
+(void)configureSegmentedControls {

   [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTintColor:[COLOR_PROXY highlightColor]];

   [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundColor:[COLOR_PROXY darkBackgroundColor]];

   [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:[UIImage new] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

   NSDictionary *selectedAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[FONT_PROXY fontNormalOfSizeSmall],
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};

   [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:selectedAttributes
                                               forState:UIControlStateSelected];

   NSDictionary *normalAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[FONT_PROXY fontNormalOfSizeSmall],
               NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[COLOR_PROXY highlightColor]};

   [UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:normalAttributes
                                               forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   NSDictionary *disabledAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[FONT_PROXY fontNormalOfSizeSmall],
                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[COLOR_PROXY lightGrayTextColor]};

   [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:disabledAttributes forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
}
```

to this:

```
???
```

Comment: what did you try in those 5 hours then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

only solution (for appearance) I've found is using images only...

```
UIImage *activeImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_bg_active"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIImage *inactiveImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_bg_inactive"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance]  setBackgroundImage:inactiveImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance]  setBackgroundImage:inactiveImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance]  setBackgroundImage:activeImage forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance]  setBackgroundImage:inactiveImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance]  setDividerImage:[UIImage new] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance]  setDividerImage:[UIImage new] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance]  setDividerImage:[UIImage new] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this appearance like this:

```
self.segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
self.segmentedControl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.segmentedControl.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
```

Replace `[UIColor whiteColor]` with the background color of the segmented control's superview.

Comment: same as answer from Dh1_Bh1

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the segments (using setWidth:forSegmentAtIndex:) so you can easily make the left and right end segments larger (say 10px larger) than the others and then you can crop off 10px from either end and have square corners. You don't have to make it larger than the screen width, instead put it inside a UIView and use it to crop the ends.

On the other hand just could just make your own segmented control using a set of custom UIButtons inside a UIControl.

Comment: I think this has the same problem as most of the responses. I wanted to set the appearance of segmented control not particular instance. But still good answer. It is  good solution for instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
segmentControl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
segmentControl.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
segmentControl.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

**if background color is white then**

```
segmentControl.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
segmentControl.layer.borderWidth = 1.5;
segmentControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: u tried above code ? because in clearColor case segmentControl  not visible

Comment: I've seen this many times. It works, but only for instance of segmented control. Maybe u didn't notice I tried to set appearance of segmentedControl. I've solve it by setting background images. Still thanks for response ;)

Answer (score 0):

using images this may be achieved.

```
    [segmented setImage:nil forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [segmented setImage:nil forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [segmented setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [segmented setTitle:@"1" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [segmented setTitle:@"2" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [segmented setDividerImage:[self imageFromColor2:[UIColor darkGrayColor] withFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, segmented.frame.size.height)]
           forLeftSegmentState:(UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted)
             rightSegmentState:(UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted)
                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [segmented setBackgroundImage:[self imageFromColor2:[UIColor lightGrayColor] withFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, segmented.bounds.size.width/2.0+1, segmented.frame.size.height)]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

to create color images:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromColor2:(UIColor *)color withFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    CGRect rect = frame;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

and as a result i had this segmented control. you can play with the colors and get what you want.

[image: result of code]

Comment: this one is closest to my solution although it also doesn't work with appearance of segmented control.